# ASP.NET Core call controller in and invoke Filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an `OrdersController` which has a CreateAsync method. Purpose of this controller is to create order.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Log]
[FancyFilter]
[AnotherFancyFilter]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] Order order)
{
   await doSomeDataProcessing(order);

   await this.repository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Now I have a story to create an bulk/batch import of orders. I am going to create controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Import([FromBody] Order[] orders)
{
   foreach (var order in orders)
   {
      await doSomeDataProcessing(order);
   }
   
   await this.repository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

However, I need to invoke some filters for each order. So, idea is to create a proxy call.. kind of

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Import([FromBody] Order[] orders)
{
   foreach (var order in orders)
   {
      var proxyController = new OrdersController();

      // I need to call/invoke CreateAsync method and all filters/attributes need to be called
      await proxyController.CreateAsync(order);
   }
}
```

Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: How you are going to handle failure? Suppose you have 100 orders and 20 was unsuccessful. How you are going to show it?

Comment: You can call them as a method like `new controller.action()` with parameter.

Comment: Are sure about creating a controller with its constructor? How about its own dependencies?

Comment: Guys, it is just a very simplified version of the real code. Question is: how to invoke method call, not how to report failures to user or how to handle dependency injection. Thanks

Comment: 1. You can use HttpClient and make calls to `CreateAsync`, but keep in mind you have to copy all needed headers (like auth headers)
2. You can share logic from filters: move logic into some specific class and use instance of that class in a controller.